# jQuery how to prepend div only once per call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mouseover

I want:

1. on ul 'hover on' prepend a `div#object1` to body.
2. on the 'hover off' remove that `div#object1`.
3. repeat

The problem is that, although it is possible to prepend `div#object1` on 'hover on' it does so more than once.

Hence my question how to prepend `div#object1` only once per call?

I've also tried it with `one()` but the second time I hover on, the `div#object1` is not prepended. In other words, `one()` does not work on the second call.

Here's my code ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24e9cnsa/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul#menu').one('mouseover', function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="object1"></div>');
  });

  $('#menu li a#omnie').mouseover(function() {
    $('div#object1').stop().animate({
      right: 530,
      top: 8,
      opacity: 1
    }, 100);
  });

  $('#menu li a#oferta').mouseover(function() {
    $('div#object1').stop().animate({
      right: 445,
      top: 8,
      opacity: 1
    }, 100);
  });

  $('#menu').mouseleave(function() {
    $('div#object1').fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: `$('ul#menu').on('mouseover', function() {`  use it

Comment: $('ul#menu').on('mouseenter', function() { seems to work because of 'mouseenter' is better than 'mouseover' -> the prepend is triggered only once 

but on mouseleave it adds one additional div

Answer (score 0):

Using `.one` isn't going to help you, what that does is automatically unbinds the handler after one call, and it never gets called again, even if you hover on it at some later point.

What you should use is `.on('mouseenter')` instead of `.on('mouseover')`.

Each time your mouse enters the `#menu` list either from outside or from one of its child items, `mouseover` is triggered.

On the other hand, `mouseenter` is only triggered when your mouse enters the `#menu` and not triggered when you hover back from its children.

```js
$('#parent').on("mouseover mouseenter", function(e) {
  $('#' + e.type).text(
    parseInt($('#' + e.type).text()) + 1
  );
});
```

```css
#parent {
  background: teal;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
}

#child {
  background: orange;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  color: black;
}

#event {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center
}

#parent,#child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="event">
  Mouseover: <span id="mouseover">0</span> Mouseenter: <span id="mouseenter">0</span>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <h3>Parent</h3>
  <div id="child">
    <h3>Child</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```